# Conditional for onChange function not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am a RN newbie and I just finished a tutorial where I was able create a component where you select a number while circle dragging.  However, now I want the color to change with each different value/number as I drag it. For now, I have it written so that when value equals the number 2, it changes to red.  My initial thought was to create a conditional in my onChange function, but that has not worked so far. It doesn't break at all, but it doesn't change color.  Does anyone have any recommendations?  Code is below and image of what I made as well.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import CircleSizeSelector from "react-native-circle-size-selector";
type State = {
  value: number
};
const InitialValue = 1;
export default class CircleSize extends Component<void, State> {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Question of the day",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
        headerTitleStyle: "bold"    
      };
  state: State = {
    value: InitialValue
  };
  onChange = (value: number) => {
    this.setState( value => {
      if (value === "number") {
        if (this.onChange.value === "2"){
        return { color: "red"};
        }
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View>
              <Text style={styles.question}>On a scale from 1 to 10, how do you rank Sunday's episode?</Text>
          </View>
        <View style={styles.parent}>
          <CircleSizeSelector
            minValue={1}
            maxValue={10}
            initialValue={InitialValue}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          >
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.value}</Text>
            </View>
          </CircleSizeSelector>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Image of that I created. Would like to have the colors change as I drag and change the value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change with each different value/number as I drag, I have defined a Color array and select the Color according to value set in state .

Here is my code

```
import CircleSizeSelector from "react-native-circle-size-selector";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const colors = [
  "#FF6633",
  "#FFB399",
  "#FF33FF",
  "#FFFF99",
  "#00B3E6",
  "#E6B333",
  "#3366E6",
  "#999966",
  "#99FF99",
  "#B34D4D"
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1
  };

  onChange = value => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const backgroundColor = colors[value - 1];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CircleSizeSelector
          minValue={1}
          maxValue={10}
          initialValue={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          currentValueCircleStyle={{
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor
          }}
          resizingCurrentValueCircleStyle={{
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor
          }}
        >
          <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        </CircleSizeSelector>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  }
});
```

[See The App Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNRTM.gif)

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The conditional will work with some tweaking to the way you call `this.setState` [1]. The updater version of `setState` takes a function which takes the entire application state and returns the state to be merged - your current implementation has some issues with shadowing the changed value coming in to the `onChange` handler. But based on what you've described I think you should be able to use the simpler `stateChange` version of `setState` which just returns an object to merge into the component state. You can also call `setState` multiple times and updates will be batched.

```
onChange = (value: number) => {
    // update state.value to the value from the SizeSelector
    this.setState({value});
    // conditionally change the color
    // this setState will get batched with the above if it executes
    if (value === 2) {
       this.setState({color: 'red'});
    }
  };
```

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

You can add color to state:

```
state: State = {
  value: InitialValue,
  color: 'blue'
};
```

Then change `onChange` function according condition:

```
onChange = (value: number) => {
  this.setState({ value })
  if (value===2) {
    this.setState({ color: 'red' })
  }
```

Finally change style for `CircleSizeSelector` component depending on `state.color`. I do not know exactly how it will looks, but something like this:

```
currentValueCircleStyle = { { backgroundColor: this.state.color } }
```